# College Scorecard API call returns all data in .json but only two fields in .csv

Tags: collegescorecard, csv, json

I'm trying to pull debt data from College Scorecard for Texas institutions using the following call:

https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools.csv?school.state_fips=48&_page=0&_fields=ope6_id,school.name,2011.aid.loan_principal,2011.aid.median_debt.completers.overall&api_key=xxxx

I get no errors and all available data in .json, but as soon as I switch to .csv the resulting spreadsheet contains only ope6_id and school.name.

I'd welcome any advice on troubleshooting the issue or converting the results from .json into something easier to work with for a novice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Many apologies for this issue, and also for this slow response. Open Data Maker hasn't had much work done on it recently, but we're currently in the process of transitioning it to new maintainers. Meanwhile you can track this issue here: https://github.com/18F/open-data-maker/issues/231